# Phalcon commands work in normal cmd but doesn't in console2

Tags: windows-8, command-line, console2

I can use Phalcon commands (phalcon is php framework) in my classic command line that's ok. But I have downloaded console2 and here I can't use phalcon commands. Do I have to do some task to get access, to same commands in console2 as in my classic command line?

thx for any help.

Comment: Relogon or reboot.

Comment: LoL it was reallz reboot :D :D I forgot rule number one :D 

thx :D